# PHP how come one element of the array is by reference and the other by value when passing a two element array as a by value parameter?

Tags: php, parameter-passing, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Can someone explain this strange behaviour I am witnessing in PHP 8.1.6?

I guess the behaviour is according to standards, I just don't understand it. The function call has a parameter by value, yet the array is changed after the call, all because of the reference to the first element.

```
$arr = [3, 4];
$ref = &$arr[0] ;             // this statement causes the weird behaviour. Without it all is ok

print_r($arr);                // as expected
print_r(doSomethingTo($arr)); // as expected
print_r($arr);                // WHAT JUST HAPPENED?

function doSomethingTo($arr) {
    // $arr BY VALUE
    foreach($arr as $k => $v)
        $arr[$k]=$v+1 ;
    return $arr ;
}
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 5
)
Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 4
)
```

Why? Why does the reference to the first array element change the behaviour of the by value parameter passing? The first element was now passed by reference to the function, and the second by value! ???

Thank you for an explanation!

Comment: There are some weird bugs related to references, this looks like one of them.

Comment: I reproduced it in 7.4.1 and 5.6.

Comment: Use `var_dump()` instead of `print_r()` and you can see where you're creating the reference on _both_ sides of the operation. https://3v4l.org/DXWNd My general recommendation is to simply _not_ use references unless you have a rock-solid understanding of [What references are and are _not_](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) [notably, not pointers] and an inescapable reason that you _have_ to use a reference, as they seldom work as you would expect.

Comment: @Barmar if it's a bug it's been present since PHP4.

Comment: @Sammitch So it's probably by design.

Comment: @Barnar I assumed already it is by design. I found also at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php (thank you @Sammitch) just BEFORE the header "Pass By Reference" the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little complex formulated answer I found at https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php

I will translate the answer to this particular situation.

The thing many people may not realise, is, is that `$a =& $b` does not mean that $a references now to $b, but $a and $b BOTH become references to the same *value* that was originally contained in $b.

So when evaluating `$ref = &$arr[0] ;` the $arr[0] element and the $ref become *both* references to the 3 value.

Now when an array is passed as a parameter by value, the array is always duplicated. Same happens here.

Which means the $arr[0] *reference* is duplicated too, i.e. in the duplicate array *another* reference is created to the same 3 value. So we have $ref, the original $arr[0] **and** the $arr[0] within the function *all* being references to the 3 value.

When either of these three references gets an assignment, of course the value changes.

Thank you @Sammitch for setting me on the right track!!!

Comment: The hard part for me to realize is, that a normal variable or array value is NOT a single reference to a value, as a file name is a single link to a file. With files, you can have one or more links to the same file, all links just being different filenames for the same file. Adding a new link doesn't change the file or the behaviour of actions performed on it. Not so with variables and array elements. The behaviour there changes once a reference is made. It actually becomes a whole different beast. That is the biggest lesson,